# How to correctly update value of IntegerProperty in the view?

Tags: kotlin, javafx, tornadofx

I am building simple application that will track a certain tabletop game of 2 players.

I have a view called `MatchView`

```
class MatchView : View() {

    // data
    private var currentRound = SimpleIntegerProperty(0)
    private var currentTurn = SimpleIntegerProperty(0)

    override val root = borderpane {
        center = label(currentRound.stringBinding{ "Round %d".format(it) })
        // other layout-related stuff
        subscribe<EndTurnEvent> {
            endPlayerTurn()
        }
    }

    private fun endPlayerTurn() {
        // increment turn
        currentTurn.plus(1)
        currentRound.plus(currentTurn.value % 2)
    }
}
```

that is subscribed to `EndTurnEvent` - event emitted by one of the fragments used by view.
The called method is supposed to increment value of `currentTurn` and if needed `currentRound` (round increments after second player ends their turn)

However neither the value of `currentRound` nor the one of `currentTurn` are getting increased when i call `.plus()` method.

I have tried editting values differently :

```
private fun endPlayerTurn() {
    // increment turn
    currentTurn.value = currentTurn.value + 1
    currentRound.value = currentTurn.value % 2
}
```

But this throws me `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread`

I am aware that putting properties into views is anti-pattern, but since I just want to keep track of 2 properties, I thought I could put them directly into `View`

Comment: the error tells you what's wrong - make sure the change happens on the fx thread :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
        // Update GUI from another Thread here
    });
```

Comment: There is also a short form in TornadoFX, so you can simply write `runLater {}`

Comment: Thanks, this worked with direct `value` manipulation. But `SimpleIntegerProperty.plus()` still doesn't work, any ideas why?

Comment: `SimpleIntegerProperty.plus()` seems to be TornadoFX specific and i can't help with it. Maybe someone else can help. In JavaFx it would be `currentTurn.set(currentTurn.get() + 1);`

Comment: perhaps @EdvinSyse  knows the answer?

Comment: The TornadoFX `plus` extension function creates a new property, it doesn't modify the existing. So while it looks like you're assigning a new value to the existing property, you're actually just creating a new property and discarding it right away :)